# thread from static method Java

Tags: java, multithreading

What I want to do is, pass `clientId` to `ClearSession()` and use `clientId` in `run()` to call `session.loadByLastAccessed()`. But the error it throws is...

```
Service.java:117: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context 
    at Thread t = new Thread(new ClearSession(clientId)) (since it is inner class)
```

If I change the class to be `static`, it will throw an error on `session.loadByLastAccessed(entityManager, clientId);` since `entityManager` is `non-static`.

Any ideas on how to `start()` a thread from a `static` method and pass a `non-static` variable?

This is my code...

```
private EntityManager entityManager; //declared within class along with code below.


public static void initClients()
        throws SessionServiceException
    {
        Properties properties = ApplicationConfig.getInstance().getProperties();
        Set<Object> keys = properties.keySet();
        String clientId = null;
        for (Object keyObject : keys)
        {
            String key = (String)keyObject;
            if (key.startsWith(SessionFactory.CLIENT_PREFIX))
            {
                clientId = StringUtils.substringAfter(key, SessionFactory.CLIENT_PREFIX);
                SessionFactory.getSessionIntf(clientId);
            }
        }

        if(!StringUtils.equals("branch", clientId ))
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ClearSession(clientId));
            t.start();
        }
    }

private class ClearSession implements Runnable 
{
    private String clientId = "";

    public ClearSession(String clientId) 
    {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
            // Pause for 2 hours
            Thread.sleep(7200000);
            // get client session
            AbstractImpl session = SessionFactory.getSessionIntf(clientId);
            session.loadByLastAccessed(entityManager, clientId);

        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            throw ie;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. You can pass any parameters to the `Runnable` as you pass the `clientId`, a thread doesn't care about from which method it is started... static or not. BTW, don't use singletones, learn IoC and DI, the Guice or the Spring frameworks.

Comment: Please rephrase the question, It's confusing. I can only understand you want to call a non static method in static method.

Comment: This looks like a scheduled task to me, you could use Quartz instead and you wouldn't have to care about initializing any thread.

Comment: This is the error it throws:\service\SessionService.java:117: non-static variable this cannot be referenced
from a static context
                Thread t = new Thread(new ClearSession(clientId));
                                      ^

Comment: All, What I want to do is, pass clientId to ClearSession() and use clientId in run() to call session.loadByLastAccessed(). but the error it throws is:Service.java:117: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context Thread t = new Thread(new ClearSession(clientId)). If I change the class to be static, It will throw an error on session.loadByLastAccessed(entityManager, clientId); since entityManager is non-static. Hope this clears up something.

Comment: I dont see you reffering to 'this' in your static method

Answer (score 0):

I see now. You have `private class`, it means it is inner class. By default inner classes implicitly reference outer class's `this`. Just declare the class as `private static class` or just move it outside.

Comment: Thanks for your reply kan. If I make the class static, this line will throw an error:session.loadByLastAccessed(entityManager, clientId) since entityManager is non-static. If I move it outside, I will have to somehow pass entityManager to outside class, which again is a problem. I cannot change entityManager to be static. I've tried quiet a few things, using anonymous innerclass, firing thread from another place, but then I loose access to entityManager.

Comment: @DJDesai That's the problem. You don't have an access to the `entityManager` inside the static method. So, it is nothing to do with threads or inner classes. You have to reorganize the code. Please, don't use global variables and singletones, use DI, IoC containers.

Comment: @DJDesai also, it is wrong way, you waste a whole thread just to sleep 2 hours. Use a scheduler, either quartz or `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`.